# Multi-dimensional arrays in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote a Fortran code that reads in multiple files. Each file has 3 columns and 1448 rows. I would like to read the files row by row, and save the values of the column3[i] to a file. In Python, I would read the files one by one, take the ith value in column3 and append to a file that has been initialised. I'm not sure how I would do that in Fortran.

```
module variables
type string
character(len=99), allocatable :: str 
end type string
end module variables

program readfiles
use variables
implicit none

real :: coorda, coordb, coordc
integer :: i, j, N, zeta, lam, k, rows
Logical, Save :: first_time = .True.
CHARACTER(len=100) :: FN 
type(string) :: array(3)
N=3 !--arbitrary number of files 
lam=80
array(1)%str = '2e8'
array(2)%str = '2e9'
array(3)%str = '3e9'

if(first_time) then
open (unit=98, file='output.txt')
DO I=1,N
lam = lam + 60
zeta=20
do j=1,N
    zeta = zeta + 20
    do k=1,N
                    WRITE(FN,10)lam, zeta, (array(k)%str)!,k=1,N)

                    OPEN(99,FILE=FN, action='read', status='old', position='rewind')!open the file to read
                   do rows=1, 1448
                   read (99,*) coorda, coordb, coordc
                   write (98, '(f13.10)') coordc     !this gives the formatting. 10 digits after decimal??
                   end do

                    CLOSE(99)   !this ensures it closes d file it is reading from so a new one can b opened for reading          

    enddo
enddo
END DO
close(98)
10 FORMAT('4e3_2048_',(I3.0),'_',(I2.2),'_',(A3),'.ksz_cl.txt') !length of this is decided by FN
endif

end program readfiles
```

Comment: That's not very far off as long as you initialise x, FN=98, there is a format statement with label 10, and you use valid variable names for col-a etc.. I suggest you write a complete program to do what you need and then come back here with that if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @IanBush. I've edited the post to include the whole code. The output gives me the entire coordc for the files, but what I want is the ith value of coord c written to file for all the 1448 rows of the 27 files I have. In Python, it would be something like this.           for i in range(len(dfs[0])):                            
        row = []
        for df in dfs:
            row.append(df['c'][i])
        cls.append(row)

Comment: To answer properly we really need the variables module, but I suspect all you need to do is open unit 98 just once, before the loop structure, and the close it after all the loops. Or alternatively open it as you have but with access='append'. But I'm slightly guessing as I don't really speak python.

Comment: Opening unit 98 before the loops writes out all the elements in coordc for the first file only. I've edited the code above to add the variables module @IanBush

Comment: Please edit your code in the question to show the current state

Comment: I've done so @IanBush